# IIS dynamic redirect rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am writing a number of redirect rules in IIS and need some guidance to make them as dynamic as possible.

I want to have a rule that goes from `/foldername/*` to `/newfolder/foldername/*`

And the file name to be appended to the end in each case. The part I'm struggling with it getting the `foldername` to be added to the result.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<rule name="Rule name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^foldername"  />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/newfolder/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

In the above example I want to be able to carry over the original folder location and file name. `{R:1}` only carries the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised `{R:1}` was carrying the file name because when I tested it wasn't the case.

Anyway, to do what you want, you have to change the pattern from `^foldername` to `^foldername/(.*)`. This way, `{R:0}` will contain the whole path (when using `^foldername`, `{R:0}` contains only the part starting with and matching `foldername`).

You rule will go as:

```
<rule name="Rule name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^foldername/(.*)"  />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/newfolder/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```